# Display: table property is not working, I want a table without using table element

Tags: html, css, html-table, display

I want to create a table using the css property display: table but not using table element.
Looked for examples as well but didn't help.
Can anybody create a fiddle so of table having atleast 3 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score -1):

**This example** displays the usage of the following `display` values:

- `table`
- `table-row`
- `table-cell`
- `table-header-group`
- `table-row-group`
- `table-footer-group`

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
}

#table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#thead {
  display: table-header-group;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

#tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='table'>
  <!-- table head -->
  <div id="thead">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">head 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">head 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- table body -->
  <div id="tbody">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">cell 1.1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">cell 1.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">cell 2.1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">cell 2.1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- table foot -->
  <div id="tfoot">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">foot 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">foot 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- table end -->
</div>
```